# SignalR transmission lean-ness?

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

Does SignalR send the entire name of the callback method between the server and client every single time, or is there an encoding?

Example :

If I'm invoking a method named SetChatModeType on the server, it sends the entire method name the first time.  But the next time I invoke it, the client and server both encoded the method name to fit in just a few bytes as opposed to sending the entire 'SetChatModeType'.

This is more of a curiosity than anything.  I'm not invoking anything frequently enough for this to matter but it could be a deciding factor for me down the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does appear to send that information from the Server to the Client, *(parameter `"M":"clientMethod"` i.e. `"M":"SetChatModeType"`)*. [This article](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/ranw/2013/02/17/signalr-protocol/) dissects how the protocol works.

Example message format, *explained in the article*.

Client –> Server

```
{"H":"hubName", "M":"MethodName", "A":[arguments], "I":messageNumber }
```

Server –> Client

```
{"C":"B,6|O,0|P,0|Q,0", "M":[{"H":"hubName", "M":"clientMethod", "A":[arguments]}]}
```

The relevant response DTO, that triggers the client method is [defined here](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/Hubs/ClientHubInvocation.cs).

---

As @PatrickFletcher points out, [this article](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/performance-and-scaling/signalr-performance) is a good resource for increasing SignalR performance and specifically addresses the issue of message size and how to reduce it.

Comment: There's a code sample for slimming down SignalR messages for high-traffic scenarios under "Reducing Message Size" in this article: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/performance-and-scaling/signalr-performance

Comment: @PatrickFletcher That's a great addition to this answer. Thanks for pointing that out. :)